# Route constraint asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

This is my Route config:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "AdsCategories",
            url: "Ads/{key}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Ads", action = "Index" },
            //constraints: new { key =  },
            namespaces: new string[] { "Vprok.Controllers" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new string[] { "Vprok.Controllers"}
        );
```

How to create a constraint "AdsCategories"?
I need use default route, if action in controller "Ads" == {key}.

Answer (score 9):

So basically if `{key}` is an existing action you want it to be handled by the default route instead of using the `Index` action on the `Ads` controller?

In order to achieve that you could list all the possible actions in the key constraint:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "AdsCategories",
    url: "Ads/{key}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Ads", action = "Index" },
    constraints: new { key = @"^create|update|delete" },
    namespaces: new string[] { "Vprok.Controllers" }
);
```

In this example the `AdsCategories` route will match only if the url is not `ads/create` or `ads/update` or `ads/delete`. For example `ads/foobar` will match.

Comment: Thank you for this variant.
But I would like to not have to everytime change routetsonfig when new action added in controller.

Comment: In this case you could write a custom constraint: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-custom-route-constraint-cs where you will dynamically verify whether the action exists or not. Obviously this will be much slower as it will have to make this evaluation on each request. I would go with the regex route.

Answer (score 1):

take the following code out:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "AdsCategories",
            url: "Ads/{key}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Ads", action = "Index" },
            //constraints: new { key =  },
            namespaces: new string[] { "Vprok.Controllers" }
        );
```

just create an index actionresult on ads controller and add a id parameter to it! DONE